# Why doesn't AsyncTypeahead not render my options?

Tags: reactjs

I have an `AsyncTypeahead` component in my application. Here's the code for it. It is based on the documents provided, and I can replicate the GitHub user example.

```
const SEARCH_URI = 'http://localhost:8005/products/products/';

const SearchProduct = () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

    const handleSearch = (query) => {
        setIsLoading(true);

        fetch(`${SEARCH_URI}?format=json&search=${query}`)
            .then((resp) => resp.json())
            .then((resp) => {
                const options = resp.map((i) => ({
                    logo: i.manufacturer.logo ? i.manufacturer.logo : default_logo,
                    manufacturer: i.manufacturer.name,
                    id: i.id,
                    name: i.name,
                }));
                setOptions(options);
                setIsLoading(false);
            });
    };

    return (
        <AsyncTypeahead
            id="prod-search"
            isLoading={isLoading}
            labelKey="name"
            minLength={3}
            onSearch={handleSearch}
            options={options}
            placeholder="Search for your favorite cars..."
            renderMenuItemChildren={(option, {text}, props) => (
                <Fragment>
                    <img
                        alt={option.manufacturer}
                        src={option.logo}
                        style={{
                            height: '24px',
                            marginRight: '10px',
                            width: '24px',
                        }}
                    />
                    <Highlighter search={text}>
                        {option.name} 
                        <div>
                            <small>{option.manufacturer}</small>
                        </div>
                    </Highlighter>
                </Fragment>
            )}
        />
    )
};
```

An example of my API response is as follows:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    category: 1,
    manufacturer: {id: 1, name: 'Bantam', logo: null, description: ''},
    name: 'BS1234',
    description: '',
    active: true,
  },
  // ... more items here...
];
```

Despite search results in the response and the fact that the options are being created and set, I can't get the options window to render.

I tried converting the `renderMenuItemChildren` into a function wrapping the React element and tried to put a console.log in it, but it never triggers. I do have a `setOptions`, and my `labelkey` is correct I think. What am I missing? How can I debug this further?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had to sleep over it. Here's the answer:

The `Highlighter` component requires a (case-insensitive) match between the text being searched for and the text that is supposed to be highlighted.

My issue I was searching on the Manufacturer ("Bantam"), but the string to be rendered is "BS1234". Searching on the latter renders the component. I guess I should play with the `Highlighter` options to make it work as I expect it to.

I'd still like pointers on how to debug the life cycle of a React component in general though.